# Vapor filters are ambiguous in context

Tags: swift, vapor, vapor-fluent

why this works when directly in router.swift

```
router.delete("users", User.parameter, "books", Book.parameter, "favourite") { req -> Future<HTTPStatus> in
    try req.parameters.next(User.self).flatMap { user in
        try req.parameters.next(Book.self).flatMap { book in
            UserBookWatched.query(on: req).filter(\.userID == user.id!).filter(\.bookID == book.id!).first().flatMap { books in
                if let books = books {
                    return books.delete(on: req).transform(to: HTTPStatus.noContent)
                }

                return req.future().transform(to: HTTPStatus.notFound)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this one does not work in route controller

```
// userid hardcoded, book from Book.parameter 
func removeBookFromFavourited(_ req: Request) throws -> Future<HTTPStatus> {
    let user = User(id: StaticUser.id)

    try req.parameters.next(Book.self).flatMap(to: HTTPStatus.self) { book in
        UserBookFavourited.query(on: req)
            .filter(\.userID == user.id!)
            .filter(\.bookID == book.id!)
            .first().flatMap { books in
            if let books = books {
                return books.delete(on: req).transform(to: HTTPStatus.noContent)
            }

            return req.future().transform(to: HTTPStatus.notFound)
        }
    }
}
```

it drops error that   `.filter(\.userID == user.id!)` "Type of expression is ambiguous in this context"

models are properly defined as pivot

thx in advance for help(edytowane)
static user will be replaced with JWT token sent in request headers

Comment: you could replace `return req.future().transform(to: HTTPStatus.notFound)` with `return req.future(.notFound)`

Comment: `user.id!` don't use force unwrapping cause it is bad practice, instead just use `user.requireID()`

Comment: thank you @imike for suggestions. I will try this

Comment: are you sure that `.first()` will return `books`? it looks like there should be `.all()` instead

Comment: this is naming error. this method should remove only one particular book not the all

Comment: If it shows `Type of expression is ambiguous in this context` try to simplify the expression e.g. to `return try UserBookFavourited.query(on: req).filter(\UserBookFavourited.userID == user.requireID())` and remove all other lines from this function and check if it compiles

Comment: error was found on discord by 0xTim - I forgotten to import Fluent in this file. see answer below

Comment: yeah it was obvious but I wanted to spot what I wrote above about

Comment: I tried simplify but error progressed to next line until I removed all filters. Thank you @imike for all replacement suggestions. I learn vapor for two weeks only now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

error was so obvious ...

lack of: `import Fluent` in header of RouteCollection file

Comment: yeah and also sometimes you will need to import `FluentSQL` also e.g. to support `~~` operator to query like this `.filter(\.bookId ~~ [1, 2, 3, 4])`